# Complex regular expression also picks additional characters

Tags: regex

I need a hand with my regular expression.

I have provided an example of a text block I am currently working on. I am trying to work out a regular expression which could extract all those strange codes. The problem is the expression also picks digits as a part of the date/time, which I would like to avoid. I saved results here on [regular expression online](https://regex101.com/r/KCF1Sc/5) website. The expression I have been working with so far is following:

```
(?<![.,:;-])(f[0-9]*[/][0-9]+|[0-9]+f|[a-z]*[0-9]{2,}(j[a-z]?)?)(?![.,:;-])
```

I hoped lookarounds would work to prevent from selecting the digits in date/time. I also tried to add "new line" characters there but it does not solve the problem. How can I sort it out?

Thanks

This is the example of text block:

```
    2017-01-01 19:30:00.000
    something something
    2017-01-01 19:30:00.000
    xxx aaa bbb 1234f
    12345f bbb aaaaa xxx aaaa 2345f xxx
    f1/234 aaa bbb
    f/1234 xxx yyy
    aaa bbb ccc ddd f6/789
    a11j's aaaaa
    b12j's aaaaa
    c13j aaaaa
    d14j aaaaa
    e15 aaaaa
    1234j
    1234ja
    2345jb
    123456jc
    ab1234 something something cd234
    2016-05-30 19:30:00.000
```

Comment: Could you explain your wanted matching rules a bit more? This is asking for a python regex, correct?

Comment: [Add word boundaries](https://regex101.com/r/KCF1Sc/3).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (and by looking at your example) your *codes* contain both letters and digits. Then this should do it for you:

```
(?=[\w/]*\d)(?=[\w/]*[a-z])[\w/]+
```

It uses two positive look-aheads. The first make sure the sequence matched contains a digit `\d` - (change to [0-9] if your flavor (which should be tagged) doesn't support it (I'm guessing python since that's slected at regex101)). The second makes sure it contains a letter.

After that it simply matches the *sequence*.

Note that all *sequence matching* also allows the `/` character, since that appears to be an allowed character in the *codes*.

[Your regex101 updated](https://regex101.com/r/KCF1Sc/2).

**Edit**

Or simpler - just make letters in the third alternation of your regex mandatory by changing `*` to a `+`, thus keeping your logic for *codes*.

```
(?<![.,:;-])(f\d*/\d+|\d+f|[a-z]+\d{2,}(j[a-z]?)?)(?![.,:;-])
                                ^ here
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KCF1Sc/4).

Comment: thanks for help. I must confess that I forgot to prepare most representative example. I have updated the question with a few new codes. If I change `*` to `+` the new codes are not picked up. It looks like your solution is the one. Thanks :)

Comment: I am also surprised how compact reg. exp. can be :)